# Are any processes in nature distributed exactly normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

A lot has been said about importance of normal distributions in nature. A lot of measurements like height or weight are distributed approximately  normal. But none of them are exactly normal, as far as I understand.

Considering normal distribution is one of the [maximum entropy distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Specified_variance:_the_normal_distribution), it seems plausible that nature should "like it". But after some thinking I couldn't come up with any examples of "really" normal random variables.

My question is *what good examples of exactly normally distributed random variables out there?*

Comment: [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion).

Comment: @mpiktas Brownian motion is a model; is there any evidence that any observed process is actually *exactly* Gaussian? I'd be quite surprised, because there's always going to be physical limitations that contradict properties of the normal.

Comment: Define "exactly".

Comment: @Glen_b is it possible to prove that any observed random quantity has an exact distribution?

Comment: @mpiktas That's what the OP appears to be asking for, though - exactly normally distributed variables; I'd have thought the only possible answer is that there can't be any.

Comment: I think this is a bit like asking for an example of a *perfectly* straight line.  They don't exist in nature, but they are still a useful concept.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean "exactly" precisely enough, then I think the answer is "no" because any natural event has a limited population (even if the population is very large) so no probability will be exactly correct.

Also the normal distribution applies to continuous variables and nothing is really continuous. Even weight, if you get down to the subatomic level, is a count (how much does Peter weigh? Please answer in terms of protons).

Perhaps more interesting, many variables that are assumed to be normally distributed may not even be roughly normal, in typical populations.

Comment: I think you would have lots of problems if you were just protons. We prefer you the way you are.

Comment: Weight is an interesting example, because it's about as continuous as anything can get.  It depends not only on a proton count, but also on neutrons (which have a different mass than protons), electrons, energies of binding and interaction, and *altitude*, among other things.  Such considerations suggest that the question ought to be addressed by distinguishing "nature" from our theories of and models about natural objects. Moreover, the random variables of greatest interest are *derived* from others: they are *sampling distributions* of statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Some relevant published papers:

- [Mechanisms for log normal concentration distributions in the environment](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-96010-6) by August Andersson.
- [Log-normal Distributions across the Sciences: Keys and Clues: On the charms of statistics, and how mechanical models resembling gambling machines offer a link to a handy way to characterize log-normal distributions, which can provide deeper insight into variability and probability—normal or log-normal: That is the question](https://academic.oup.com/bioscience/article/51/5/341/243981)  BioScience, Volume 51, Issue 5, May 2001, Pages 341–352, [https://doi.org/10.1641/0006-3568(2001)051[0341:LNDATS]2.0.CO;2](https://doi.org/10.1641/0006-3568(2001)051%5B0341:LNDATS%5D2.0.CO;2)