# Normal distribution in nature: additive result of multiple variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

We found normal distribution is so common in nature, such as many measurement of species (weight, height or size). From the point of central Limit Theorem, Can I intuitively understand this as the additive result of multiple factors (genes affecting height) that affect corresponding phenotype (height)?

Comment: Possible dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436808/why-normal-distribution-is-so-special,https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/what-intuitive-explanation-is-there-for-the-central-limit-theorem,https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39082/can-we-see-shape-of-normal-curve-somewhere-in-nature,https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177218/are-any-processes-in-nature-distributed-exactly-normal