# Are all examples of normal distribution in nature only a consequence of CLT?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, example

I have read that many bell curves we see in nature is just a consequence of the CLT, because those things are just the result of many small additive causes (e.g. human height).

Then my question is: Are all gaussians like that? Or can we find an example of some phenomenon that follows 'pure' normal distribution, and not just due to CLT. Please, I prefer examples from nature.

Comment: The human height example is interesting because the distribution is decidedly not Normal: it is multimodal and far from Normal.  (Think about the effects of age and gender, to begin with.)  But generally, what kind of evidence would one offer for your "pure" Normal distribution?  Are there any natural phenomena that cannot be analyzed into combinations of many influences?  Unless you can give us some possible characterizations, your question appears unanswerable.

Comment: Similar:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204471/is-there-an-explanation-for-why-there-are-so-many-natural-phenomena-that-follow,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177218/are-any-processes-in-nature-distributed-exactly-normal,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39082/can-we-see-shape-of-normal-curve-somewhere-in-nature, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/real-life-examples-of-common-distributions